# Испрользование класса для подключения к базе данных

Tags: php

Почитал инструкцию про `class` и решил упростить подключение к базе данных в своём проекте!

Использую такой вид подключения к файлу:

```php
include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/office/modules/database/connection.php";
```

Как уже стало понятно в файле `connection.php` содержится скрипт для подключения к бд.

Теперь думаю использовать подключения class который уже и будет содержать в себе подключение к базе! Но класс будет получать данные с переменных которые указаны в файле!

> Думаю что в будующем сделать общий класс где и будут находится все
>   классы требуемые для работы проекта!

Пока что накидал такой вот вариант!

```php
    class connect_DB{
        function getInfoConnect($dataDB){
            echo $dataDB['host'] . "<br>";
            echo $dataDB['database'] . "<br>";
            echo $dataDB['user'] . "<br>";
            echo $dataDB['password'] . "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
            print_r($dataDB);

            //connect to DB
        }
    }

    $connect_DB = new connect_DB;

    $host = 'localhost';
    $database = 'name_dataBase';
    $user = 'name_user';
    $password = 'pass';

    $dataDB = array("host" => $host,"database" => $database,"user" => $user,"password" => $password);

    $connect_DB -> getInfoConnect($dataDB);
```

На выходе получаем это:

```
localhost
name_dataBase
name_user
pass

Array ( [host] => localhost [database] => name_dataBase [user] => name_user [password] => pass )
```

Подскажите как правильно сделать ?

Comment: https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/More/ServiceLocator/README.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не рекомендую использовать подключение к БД для ознакомления с классами. Слишком много подводных камней и бессмысленного кода. Взять к примеру данное "упрощение":

До:

```
include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/office/modules/database/connection.php";
$users = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users")->fetch_row[0];
```

после:

```
include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/office/modules/database/connection.php";
include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/office/modules/database/database.php";
$connect_DB = new connect_DB;
$dataDB = array("host" => $host,"database" => $database,"user" => $user,"password" => $password);
$connect_DB -> getInfoConnect($dataDB);
$users = $connect_DB->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users")->fetch_row[0];
```

Это правда называется упрощением? Серьёзно?

> Подскажите как правильно сделать ?

Оставить всё ак есть, только убедиться что в connection.php лежит [правильный код](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect).

И PDO, и mysqli - это уже классы, и не самые плохие. 
Поэтому я настоятельно рекомендую сначала научиться рабротать с встроенными классми РНР, а потом уже потихоньку делать свои, но не для подключения к БД, а для данных, которые получаешь из БД